# "the biggest liar of all people I have ever known" / "the biggest liar of all the others I have ever known" / "the biggest liar I have ever known"

Tags: relative-clauses, modifiers

> You are the biggest liar **of all people I have ever known**.
>
> You are the biggest liar **of all the others I have ever known**.
>
> You are the biggest liar **I have ever known**.

Are all of the sentences natural, or only the third one? Maybe, the first sentence is not polite to all society, because all of the people are some kind of liars there.

Comment: They are all natural color; not one dye job among them.

Comment: Only the third one sounds natural to me. The first two are unnecessarily wordy and the second is confusing, too.